# CTE results in Redshift error "column reference is ambiguious for code"

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

What is causing the error "column reference "col_1" is ambiguous?

```
WITH    cte1 AS
        (
        SELECT  col_1, col_4
        from table_1
        ),
        cte2 AS
        (
        SELECT  two.col_1, two.col_5, three.col_6
        from table_2 as two
        left join table_3 as three
        on two.col_1 = three.col_1 
        ),
        cte3 AS
        (
        SELECT col_1, col_10
        from table_4
)

SELECT  cte1.col_1, cte1.col_4,
        cte2.col_1, cte2.col_5, cte2.col_6,
        cte3.col_1, cte3.col_10
FROM cte1
left join cte2 on cte1.col_1 = cte2.col_6
left join cte3 on cte1.col_1 = cte3.col_10
;
```

I suspect cte2 is causing the ambiguous column name issue in the final outer query?

Comment: your cte1 and cte3 have syntax error , no  from statement

Comment: The post has been edited.

Comment: This query has no ambiguous reference to col_1. Please share complete query.

Comment: Post has been updated.

Comment: Still there is no ambiguity in query. It should run fine. Please share sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below query. Though it's using garbage data there is no ambiguous reference in the query.

```
 WITH    cte1 AS
         (
         SELECT  col_1, col_4
         from (select 1 col_1,2 col_4)d
         ),
         cte2 AS
         (
         SELECT  two.col_1, two.col_5, three.col_6
         from (select 1 col_1, 2 col_5) as two
         left join (select 1 col_1,1 col_6) as three
         on two.col_1 = three.col_1 
         ),
         cte3 AS
         (
         SELECT col_1, col_10
         from (select 1 col_1, 2 col_10) table_4
 )
 
 SELECT  cte1.col_1, cte1.col_4,
         cte2.col_1, cte2.col_5, cte2.col_6,
         cte3.col_1, cte3.col_10
 FROM cte1
 left join cte2 on cte1.col_1 = cte2.col_6
 left join cte3 on cte1.col_1 = cte3.col_10
```

Output:

| col_1 | col_4 | col_1 | col_5 | col_6 | col_1 | col_10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | null | null |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c11a00889f5704a51256e9d160c32173)*

Comment: Thanks for your help. The ambiguity was due to the same column being referenced twice - once from table_2 and the other from table_3 - in cte2.
This issue is now resolved

Comment: That's great to know. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

put it here since it doesn't fit in comment section.

as I said cte1 and cte3 are not correct statements :

```
WITH    cte1 AS
        (
        SELECT  col_1, col_4
        ),
```

it should be something like this :

```
WITH    cte1 AS
        (
        SELECT  col_1, col_4
        FROM tableName
        ),
```